# ASP MVC 5 applications stopped working with "System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

**Partly solved the moment I hit save:
The Exception settings of the failing solution were set to break on all for Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Resetting those to default allowed the project to start.**

This appears to be a solution level issue.

I have a solution with half a dozen projects in including a web project created as an MVC project.

I've not made any changes to it. it's been in the solution for a couple of months.

Today it no longer run. Initially it threw an exception saying it couldn't access Temporary ASP.NET files in the ridiculous default location of C:\Windows... So I fixed that by adding tempDirectory="..."

The next exception that occurs is:

```
System.Security.SecurityException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

The stack trace at this point is:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(System.ExceptionResource resource)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(string name, bool writable) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(string name)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.Misc.OpenAspNetRegKey(string subKey) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.Misc.GetAspNetRegValue(string subKey, string valueName, object defaultValue) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.CompilationMutex.CompilationMutex(string name, string comment)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock.CompilationLock() Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock.GetLock(ref bool gotLock) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(long cachedHash)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel)  Unknown
[AppDomain (DefaultDomain, #1) -> AppDomain (/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130855931402033459, #2)]    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(string appId, System.Type type, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, bool failIfExists, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartApplication(string appId, string appPath, out object runtimeInterface)   Unknown
```

If I create a new solution with a single web MVC web project in and run it, it starts correctly, showing the standard template.

If I add a new project to the existing solution and run it, It does not run! It throws the same access exceptions.

IF I add the existing failing project to the new working solution, it works!!

I've tried deleting all temp asp.net files, all temp files generally, stopping stuff, rebooting. Nothing works.

It's as if the solution has started with fewer rights for some reason. I'm not running either instance as administrator, and using the same shortcut icon to start VS.

This is with Visual Studio 2015. Framework is set to 4.51

Any clues at all?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new solution.sln file and re-adding all of the projects to it? If you can just replace the .sln file, that's an easy fix. Also make sure you deleted the hidden .suo file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IF I add the existing failing project to the new working solution, it works!!

Then just create a new Solution.sln file. Your projects can stay intact, just delete / replace the old sln file with a new one.

Comment: I really didn't want to recreate the solution file. The solution contains quite a few projects and a number of solution folders holding various other assets. It would probably only take 15 minutes or so to do, but as I didn't know what caused the original to break, I didn't want to be creating a new solution file repeatedly.

Comment: If the project is under source control, you could create the new solution file, then compare the old one to the new one to find out what was causing problems. I suspect maybe it is the solution level build configurations?

Comment: Yep it turned out to be the exception settings, it was breaking on all exceptions for all framework types. I think that setting lives in the suo file as it's user specific.

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this problem if I run Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator (right click Visual Studio icon -> Run as Administrator).

Answer (score 0):

Using Registry Editor, find this key

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET
```

right click, "Permissions...", "Advanced"

and add `IUSR` and "Allow Read" and apply it to "This keys and subkeys"